# Express send response insider event listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using event listeners inside the function to receive data. I need to send the data coming from event callback to the API request. But, res.send doesn't work inside the event listeners function.

```
api.get('/request/discovery', function(req, res) {
  console.log('request');
  //gapi is own module and not gapi npm
  gapi.request('myrequest', function(err, out) {

      gapi.responseEvent.on('done_task', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      // want to send data e.g: res.send(data)

      })
   })
})
```

gapi module

```
function nondiscoveryResponse(call,callback)
{
// .... all operations then . . 
    out.setMessage(true);
    var json = JSON.stringify(go);
    responseEvent.emit('done_task',json);
    //console.log(json);
    callback(null,out);
}
```

Comment: *"But, res.send doesn't work inside the event listeners function"* Yes, it does, in the general case. Looking at that code, I suspect you're not using `gapi` correctly, whatever `gapi` is. (It doesn't immediately look like [the obvious one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gapi).)

Comment: Hey! thanks but the gapi is the custom exported js module and not the gapi npm. Is the name issue? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: No, the name's not an issue. But we can't answer your question without knowing how `gapi` is meant to be used. Again, using `res.send` in an asynchronous callback is not a problem; that's a very, very normal thing to do. I think the problem is that you need to be using that `gapi` differently; registering your `done_task` callback inside the `myrequest` callback looks wrong. But without knowing what `gapi` is, we can't really help.

Comment: I added the gapi method. When I call the request function. It does the operation and executes nondiscoveryResponse. From here I am emitting an event to the main app.js to get a response.

Comment: In the statement `console.log(data);`, is the `data` printed?

Comment: Yes its getting printed